# How to change Google Maps Marker icon when user clicked the marker icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-google-maps

I created the Google Maps using tomchentw react-google-maps. The marker icon by default displays red marker icon, but whenever user clicks the marker icon it should change into grey marker icon and also increases the marker icon size. How can I changed it?

```js
<Marker
  onClick={this.MarkerClicked.bind(this,house._id)} 
  icon={{url: "/images/mapRed2.png"}} 
  position={{lat: house.location.lat, lng: house.location.lng}}
/>
```

When my marker icon is clicked it should change its icon and size.

Comment: Can't you put the icon source in state as a variable and manipulate inside MarkerClicked method?

Comment: You can try to add an eventlistener to that marker and change it on click, like here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523100/google-map-api-v3-change-marker-icon-on-click

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google map API v3 change marker icon on click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523100/google-map-api-v3-change-marker-icon-on-click)

Comment: @JohnM I don't think so, that is about a very different approach to google maps markers that wouldn't work here unless he dropped the react-google-maps approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example demonstrates how to update marker icon and size once the button is clicked:

```
const Map = compose(
    withScriptjs,
    withGoogleMap,
    withStateHandlers(() => ({
        iconUrl: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png",
        iconSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 32)
    }), {
            onMarkerClick: () => () => ({
                iconUrl: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png",
                iconSize: new google.maps.Size(64, 64)
            })
        })
)(props =>
    <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={8}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}>
        <Marker onClick={props.onMarkerClick}
            icon={{ url: props.iconUrl, scaledSize: props.iconSize }}
            position={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }} />

    </GoogleMap>
)
```

Key points:

- `icon.scaledSize` property is utilized to resize marker icon
- `iconUrl` and `iconSize` state properties are passed to `Marker`
  component once `onClick` event is triggered

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rrekr2)